# What user instead of Google Checkout Order Report API

Tags: google-play, google-checkout, android-pay

Google Checkout will no longer be supported on November 20, 2013. What I must use to get information about Android in-app billing orders?

Answer (score 2):

Android merchants can get Earnings and Sales reports through the [Google Wallet Merchant Center](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3039702).

You can also download daily sales estimates using the gsutil tool.

For more details see [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2482017?hl=en&ref_topic=15867) from the Google Play Developer Help Center.